# Automatize Publish of Application Web (VS2008)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild, automation, publish

I have a solution sln and several projects (vbproj, csproj). I have web project, and I need automatize Publish (like menu option in VS2008).

Can I replicate VS2008 "Publish Web Site" from command line ??

any help about it, please ?

Thanks in advance. Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

I did something of softs using the MSBUILD functions along with [MSBUILD Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/).

By manually editing the .csproj/.vbproj you can accomplish the same thing done by the "Publish Web Site".